# Refresh griddata on main page when child open page is updated or closed

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I want to refresh a grid datasource when there is an update happening in the database from another page. My child form is a WPF page. I open it like following:

```
Dim jobActivityWindow As New winJobDetails(DbManagerJobs.GetXamlString(jobtype, "Existing"), wrn)
EnableModelessKeyboardInterop(jobActivityWindow)
Dim helper As New System.Windows.Interop.WindowInteropHelper(jobActivityWindow)
helper.Owner = Me.MdiParent.Handle
jobActivityWindow.Show()
```

When this `jobactivitywindow` closes or anything I do(when I update database from `jobactivitywindow`), I want to update my main form (reading data from database and refreshing).